# What's the intuition behind factor grouping?

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, factor-models, mean-reversion

From the book "Finding Alpha", written by a popular quant fund WorldQuant, explains many techniques about quantitative investing but intentionally omits many of the caveats and applications of those techniques.

In the book, they introduce a concept of 'factor grouping', which is as simple as grouping stocks by their sectors/industry.

Sometimes a stock's return is demeaned by the group mean or ranked within the group.

Magically, this technique yields very good results and make an unprofitable 5-day reversion strategy to something that actually generates profit.

The book says "It works", but doesn't explain why. Why does it work? What's the intuition behind all the 'grouping' techniques?

Comment: This is commonly done, it can be seen as an attempt to achieve a better balance of industries in the final portfolio. For example if you simply buy high B/M stocks you might end up mostly with utility stocks and no tech stocks. If you buy the highest B/M in each industry you will have better balance, including some tech stocks. There are numerous published articles that compare for ex. "momentum" vs "within industry momentum". Of course there is a risk of overfitting by trying numerous variants like this.

Comment: @noob2, Thanks for the explanation. However, is there any specific papers/books that explicitly discuss these topics? Not limited to sector/industry but extends further to any other factors in general.

Comment: I don't know any general treatment, I have seen grouping on Industry, Country, or Asset Class.  For industry, one paper is Asness: *Predicting Stock Returns Using Industry-Relative Firm Characteristics* (2000). There are many others since then.

Comment: @noob2 Thanks for the reference.